# Who discovered what set of factors is responsible for visibility of celestial bodies on Earth's daytime sky?

Tags: history

Visibility of a celestial body on the sky during the day depends on a number of factors - if I recall correctly: the body's magnitude, *[Seeing](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/101/what-are-the-metrics-of-observation-conditions)*, [Sky brightness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_brightness), and probably some others I have missed.

Who was the first to discover/compile the set of variables responsible for determining, whether a celestial body remains visible with naked eye in certain (daylight) conditions?

Comment: It's awfully quiet...

Comment: It's not an easy question. This set of factors is not really all that useful in astronomy (antithesis of optimal observation conditions), still if you asked for them, you'd probably have an answer or two. Asking for a *person* puts that one more level of separation from the main focus and really on the outskirts of the site's scope.